# How to invoke onClick and onLongClick of EditText from RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener

I'm creating a compose screen for my app. I have a `ScrollView` which contains a `RelativeView` which in turn contains two things: the `EditText` where the user types a message, and an `ImageView` whose visibility is toggled on and off depending on whether an image is attached to the status or not. Here's that part of my layout XML.

```
<!-- @dimen/bigGap = 8dp -->
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/parentScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bigGap"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/bigGap"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/bigGap"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bigGap"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:background="#006400"
    > <!-- green background color -->

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/parentLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFD700"> <!-- yellow background color -->

        <EditText android:id="@+id/postText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#dddddd"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            /> <!-- gray background color -->

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/postImage"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/thumbnailSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/thumbnailSize"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@id/postText"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Because my `EditText`'s height is `wrap_content`, the whole thing starts off with a single line of gray background (the `EditText`) on top of a yellow background (the `RelativeLayout`, which fully covers the green background of the `ScrollView`). However, I'll later change all the views' backgrounds to white (to make them look like a single component) and it will be counter-intuitive for the user to be able to tap only that single line of `EditText` to make the keyboard pop up.

[image]

What I want to do is to redirect the click and long click actions of the `RelativeLayout` to the click and long click actions of the `EditText`, but my code below doesn't work. Help?

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postText);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLinearLayout);
rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Logger.d("onClick invoked!");
        editText.performClick();
    }
});
rl.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Logger.d("onLongClick invoked!");
        return editText.performLongClick();
    }
});
```

My intention here is so that when the `RelativeLayout` is clicked, the keyboard pops up (as it does when done to an `EditText`) and when long-pressed, display the cut/copy/paste/text selection options (same behavior with `EditText`).

Answer (score 1):

From the description, What you actually want is to open the keyboard. So your title for the question suggests a solution, not the actual problem.

call this from your click listener (or immediately when you show the page):

> ```
>   ((InputMethodManager) myActivity
>             .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
>             .toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
>                     InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
> ```

**Edit**:
You must also call `editText.requestFocus();` (@Phil is right), but from my experience it's not enough to open the keyboard, so you'll need also the ugly code above.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is for your `EditText` to gain focus (which in-turn causes the keyboard to show):

```
rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Logger.d("onClick invoked!");
        editText.requestFocus();
    }
});
rl.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Logger.d("onLongClick invoked!");
        editText.requestFocus();
        return true;
    }
});
```